# Sharing Mac Printer with Ubuntu (Linux)

Tags: macos, ubuntu, mac, printer, bonjour

I want to share my printer connected to my Mac with a Ubuntu Box (10.04 LTS -Lucid Lynx).

I click share printer on the Mac, and then I do a discover on the Ubuntu box ... I see the printer, I select it, and it gets added.

When I try to print - NOTHING HAPPENS - a few errors here and there. I think the URI is screwed up, but I do not know what kind of URI format the Mac wants.

URI is:

```
dnssd://HP%20LaserJet%20P3005%20%40%20hostname._ipp._tcp.local/cups
```

Should I use:

```
ipp://blah-blah-blah ?
```

or

```
http://blah-blah-blah ?
```

One error was:

> com.apple.print.recoverable+networked

There is likely one sure fire way to make this work and that is what I am looking for.

Comment: Maybe there's no correct way and you have a bug somewhere. Can you tell us *what exactly* this URI is, and *where* you see *which* errors? Rather than doing it in supplemental comments, can you [edit] your post and re-write?

Comment: Okay ... fixed up the question ...

Comment: I think this is related to the way Linux interprets a Mac Bonjour URI ... I see a URI with encoded spaces ... maybe that is what is causing the barf ... Bonjour as a service seems clunky ... cannot get my printer to print ... 

I tried IPP and I could not get that to work either.

---

Comment: I'd check to make sure the printer is compatible, are extra drivers required? http://www.openprinting.org/printers

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this as your printer URI in Linux:

http://mac:631/printers/printername

- Replace "mac" by the hostname or IP or your mac computer.
- Replace "printername" by the name assigned to the shared printer on the mac (try to avoid special chars as spaces if possible).
- You will end up having something like this:

http://192.168.0.99/printers/HPLaserJetP3005

I think it should work.